# Plotting two columns along axes with a third column determining symbols - ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My data frame consists of three columns, and looks like this:

```
year   |  theme   |   count
-----------------------------
1998      WH           13
2001      WH           38
1999      WH            5
2011      NB           11
2010      NB           29
...
```

Here's the entire data frame:

```
structure(list(year = c(2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 
2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 
1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 
1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 
1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 
1964, 1963, 1962, 1961, 1960, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2003, 1991, 
1987, 1977, 1975, 1968, 1965, 2016, 2015, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 
2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 
1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1985, 1983, 
1982, 1980, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 
2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 
2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1987, 
1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1981, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 
1967, 1964, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 
2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1996, 
1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1983, 1980, 
1979, 1978, 1976, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1967, 1965, 1962, 2016, 2015, 
2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 
2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1991, 1988, 1986, 1983, 
1982, 1980, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 
2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2000, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1991, 1990, 1983, 1979, 1976, 2016, 
2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 
2004, 2002, 2001, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 
1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1980, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 
2004, 2003, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1988, 1986, 
1985, 1984, 1983, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1998, 1997, 
1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1978, 1977, 1975, 
1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2009, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1995, 1993, 1992, 1987, 1985, 1979, 1965, 1964, 
2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 
2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1992, 
1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 
1978, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1968, 1967, 1963, 1961, 2016, 2015, 
2012, 2009, 2004, 2002, 2001, 1999, 1998, 1993, 1992, 1990, 1987, 
1985, 1979, 1965, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 
2006, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 
1991, 1988, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1976, 1975, 1973, 1968, 1961, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 
2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 
1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1982, 1980, 1979, 
1977, 1976, 1975, 1973, 1968, 1961, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2012, 2011, 
2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2000, 1998, 1996, 1995, 
1994, 1988, 1986, 1983, 1978, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 
2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 
2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 
1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1983, 1981, 1980, 1979, 
1978, 1973, 1972, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2002, 2000, 
1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1991, 1989, 1988, 1986, 1983, 
1982, 1978, 1976, 1975, 1973, 1969, 1968, 1967, 2016, 2015, 2014, 
2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 
1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1988, 1986, 1984, 
1983, 1975, 1973, 1968, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 
2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 
1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 
1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1978, 1977, 1976, 
1975, 1973, 1972, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 2016), theme = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = 
c("ALL", "AB", "BB", "BS", "CS", "DS", "EG", "FB", "GB", "KB", "KS", "LS", 
"LP", "MC", "NB", "NW", "SB", "SH", "VM", "WH"), class = "factor"), 
count = c(28, 36, 38, 22, 21, 24, 20, 36, 15, 14, 21, 12, 
16, 12, 11, 12, 15, 14, 8, 10, 3, 7, 4, 5, 10, 7, 7, 6, 5, 
15, 11, 4, 3, 6, 9, 8, 9, 5, 5, 9, 8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 
8, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 15, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 6, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 12, 4, 5, 
11, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 10, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 6, 9, 
6, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 12, 1, 11, 11, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 4, 5, 8, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
8, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 7, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 
2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 1, 4, 
4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 14, 7, 5, 
8, 9, 7, 10, 14, 6, 11, 6, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 
3, 6, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6, 4, 9, 3, 10, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 5, 12, 6, 9, 15, 9, 13, 7, 
10, 7, 8, 2, 8, 2, 5, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 2, 4, 7, 8, 1, 6, 
2, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
11)), .Names = c("year", "theme", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 
-654L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot this with 'year' along the x-axis and 'theme' along the y-axis, but with two requisites:

1. The third column 'count' should determine the symbol. Either the symbols are 
   colored, the color varying with the count, or the symbol is a line segment, 
   where the thickness of the line should increase with the count.
2. The themes should be along the y-axis, ordered with the themes appearing at
   the earlier years in the bottom of the chart.

This would be a scatter plot, where the symbols are determined by the values in a third column.

I could show you my totally unsuccessful script, but it's too much code for one post.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sort your data by year and then:
`ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=theme, color=count)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very basic way, your code could be something like that:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=theme, color=count, size=count)) +
geom_point() +
theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13), axis.title.y =element_text(size=15), axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.5), axis.title.x=element_text(size=15)) +
background_grid(major = "none", minor = "none") + 
scale_colour_gradient(low="grey", high="blue") +
panel_border()
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `background_grid` function seems to be unknown, as is `panel_border`.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping answers minimal-ish - none of the theming stuff is necessary and just serves to distract from the key components of the answer (and in this it doesn't run at all without additional unnamed packages).

Comment: Use library("cowplot"). @Gregor thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$theme = reorder(df$theme, df$year, FUN = min)

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = theme, color = count)) + geom_point()
```

You might want to remove the "all" so that it doesn't dominate the variation in `count`, we could throw a `size` in there too also depending on count.

```
ggplot(subset(df, theme != "ALL"),
       aes(
         x = year,
         y = theme,
         color = count,
         size = count
       )) + geom_point(alpha = 0.8)
```